# How can I access getSupportFragmentManager() in a static method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In my application I have two `activities` both having a **static method**. I call these methods from a separate activity. The problem is that in my static methods I am  unable to get access to `getSupportFragmentManager();` the error being produced is:

> "unable to resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()"

So how do I resolve this problem?

Comment: make the method receive a Activity parameter and call it from that reference.

Comment: "So how to solve this problem?" - Change your design. Static methods in Activities is not a good idea, and will, more often than not, just not work. You shouldn't be trying to perform Fragment transactions in an Activity that isn't currently active anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code. I think this useful for you.

```
FragmentManager ft = ((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
DialogFragment newFragment = MyNotification.newInstance();
newFragment.setCancelable(false);
newFragment.show(ft, "mydialog");
```

Answer (score 1):

> In my application I have two activities both having a static method. I
>   call these methods from a separate activity. The problem is that in my
>   static methods I am unable to get access to
>   getSupportFragmentManager();

Using a static method in an Activity which access an active part of it is usually a bad practice. It is because you can't ensure that all the activity part is still intact when in inactive state. But you can use a static method for intent creation in activity, something like this:

```
public static Intent createIntent(Activity activity, int value) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(activity, YourActivityClass.class);
  intent.put("EXTRA_VALUE", value);
  return intent;
}
```

which will hide all the extra key when you're trying to create an intent to launch an activity. Where you can call it with:

```
Intent intent = YourActivityClass.createIntent(this, 10);
startActivity(intent);
```

> the error being produced is "unable to resolve method
>   getSupportFragmentManager()". So how do I resolve this problem?

You need to modify your static method to directly required a FragmentActivity as its parameter. It is because [getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity) is part of FragmentActivity. Something like this:

```
public static void doSomething(FragmentActivity activity) {
  SupportFragmentManager manager =  activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
  ...
}
```

But with the above code, you can't access the SupportFragmentManager from the activity of the static method. So, it's kinda useless.

Or you can try:

```
public static SupportFragmentManager doSomething() {
  return  activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

But it will give you NullPointerException when the activity is destroyed or inactive (not always).